# Reorder Content Type Columns

Tags: 2010, content-type

I have a custom content type with some custom site columns. I can't find anywhere to reorder the columns for the content type. How can this be done in Sharepoint Designer 2010? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot do it from SharePoint Designer. You have to do it from browser interface. From Site Settings --> Content Types Page.

Keep in mind that you may not be able to do everything from SPD that you can do from browser interface and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "Column Order" link under "Columns" section in Manage Content Type page (_layouts/ManageContentType.aspx?ctype=0x0100EDB28B537320E749881D67FD6A9AD47C).
You can also came there directly by the following URL: _layouts/ChangeFieldOrder.aspx?ctype=0x0100EDB28B537320E749881D67FD6A9AD47C (please insert ID of your content type there)